# Find the value of $\min_{|z| \le 1} \left(max\left\{|1+z|,|1+z^2|\right\}\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, maxima-minima

if $z \in \mathbb{C}$ Then Find the value of $$\min_{|z| \le 1} \left(max\left\{|1+z|,|1+z^2|\right\}\right)$$

i assumed $z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin \theta)$

Then we have

$$|1+z|=\sqrt{(r\cos\theta+1)^2+(r\sin\theta)^2}=\sqrt{r^2+2r\cos\theta+1}$$ and similarly

$$|1+z^2|=\sqrt{r^4+2r^2\cos2\theta+1}=\sqrt{(r^2+1)^2-4r^2\sin^2\theta}\le r^2+1$$

also $$|1+z| \le r+1$$

but how to decide maximum of these two

Comment: As a hint, one way to do the problem is to find when $|1+z|$ is less than $|1+z^2|$. You can then minimize $|1+z|$ in that region, minimize $|1+z^2|$ in the other region, and find which value is less.

Comment: Using Maple, I got
$$\min_{|z| \le 1} \left(\max\left\{|1+z|,|1+z^2|\right\}\right) = \sqrt{3-\sqrt{5}}=\frac{\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{2}}{2}$$